# Remote Azure server returning NotFound error (Unauthorized)

Tags: azure, reporting-services, windows-phone-7.1, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a virtual machine on Azure with Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012 installed on it. Also i have opened inbound port 80 and 1433 open on vm.

I have created a database and reports (rdl) and deployed to the server.

When I write a simple WinForms application it is able to render the report hosted on the vm's ReportServer.

Now I am writing a WP7 application to communicate and get xml from remote server. This time I'm getting an error:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound
>
> InnerException: System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

I am not sure where the problem is; do I need to do anything from server side?

**Client Side**

Below is my config and code:

1) I have added a service reference to the reportserver as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854356/downloading-xml-file-from-sql-reporting-server) and below is ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://virtualmachine.cloudapp.net:80/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportExecutionServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel> </configuration>
```

2) Below is my code:

```cs
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient client = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient();
    client.LogonUserCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_LogonUserCompleted);
    client.LogonUserAsync("username", "password", "virtualmachine.cloudapp.net");
}
```

Here username is 'administrator' which i use to login to virtual machine. Would that be a problem?

**Server side**

Below is my Reportserver\web.config

```xml
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

And below is my Reportserver\rsreportserver.config

```xml
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
            <RSWindowsNTLM/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
<EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into your windows.azure.com account and select the VM, then select the Endpoint link at the top.

Make sure you add an endpoint, something like:

Name: ReportsEndpoint

Protocol: TCP

Public Port: 80

Private Port: 80

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for reply. I have already done those setting! And still it doesn't work.